# CKEditor 5 htmlEncodeOutput Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor 5 and unable to make htmlEncodeOutput configuration work as expected.

Following is the code snippet I'm using but even when setting the value to true the editor's element always return decoded value.

```
  ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), { htmlEncodeOutput: true})
        .then(editor => {

            editorObj = editor;              

            console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err.stack);
        });
```

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This feature is also discussed on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/698, so if you know any use case for it, feel free to comment there.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor 5 [does not have](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editorconfig-EditorConfig.html) this configuration option.

The CKEditor 5 is rewriten from scratch and does not have the same [configuration options](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config) as previous (CKEditor 4).

If you'd like to encode HTML you can use similar approach that [is used in CKEditor 4](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/45cf8e0e8a60ec547f8850d1a91594e6cf9bf98a/core/tools.js#L371) which simply replaces unsafe characters to HTML-safe - ie `&` to `&amp;`.